# how to put secrets into a configMap with podman play kube

Tags: postgresql, podman, configmap

This is for `podman play kube local-stack.yaml` which has a postgres and grafana server

I want to create a distinct grafana user & password for the database, how can I make the ConfigMap include a password (even if it's insecure, this is local-stack.yaml -- not fort knox).

Based on other stack overflow answers I don't think `podman ConfigMaps` can have any interpolation done, and almost certainly NOT from a secret vault.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-init-db-script
data:
  init-db-script.sql: |
    CREATE DATABASE grafana_db;
    CREATE USER grafana_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${GRAFANA_DB_PASSWORD}';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE grafana_db TO grafana_user;
```

```
...
  ## the database
  - name: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5432
    env:
      - name: POSTGRES_USER
        value: "admin"
      - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: postgres-vault
            key: pg_password
      - name: GRAFANA_DB_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: postgres-vault
            key: gf_password
      - name: POSTGRES_DB
        value: "postgres"
    volumeMounts:
    # If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - name: postgres-init-db-script
        mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - name: postgres-storage
        mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
...
```

I will update back here when I figure out a good answer.

I attempted to put the GF_DB_PASSWORD into the environment variable, that didn't work (the file written to the volume doesn't have the value interpolated)

Comment: ⚠️ I want to remind future me that when testing the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` scripts only run when the volume is empty! 
`podman volume rm postgres-pvc`

Answer (score 1):

My best workable solution for an extremely insecure local-stack.yaml, with podman play kube is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: extremely-insecure-env
data:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: bar
    GF_DATABASE_PASSWORD: baz
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: local-stack
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: set-permissions
    image: busybox
    volumeMounts:
    - name: postgres-init-db-script
      mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args: 
    - "chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db-script.sh"
  containers:
  ## the database
  - name: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5432
    envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: extremely-insecure-env
          optional: false
    env:
      - name: POSTGRES_USER
        value: "admin"
      - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: postgres-vault
            key: pg_password
      # we get GRAFANA_DB_PASSWORD from the extremely-insecure-env
      # - name: GRAFANA_DB_PASSWORD
      #   valueFrom:
      #     secretKeyRef:
      #       name: postgres-vault
      #       key: gf_password
      - name: POSTGRES_DB
        value: "postgres"

    volumeMounts:
    # If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - name: postgres-init-db-script
        mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - name: postgres-storage
        mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-init-db-script
data:
  init-db-script.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash

    # Connect to the PostgreSQL database using psql and execute the commands separately to avoid transaction block issues
    psql -U "${POSTGRES_USER}" -d "${POSTGRES_DB}" -c "CREATE DATABASE grafana_db;"
    psql -U "${POSTGRES_USER}" -d grafana_db -c "CREATE USER grafana_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${GF_DATABASE_PASSWORD}';"
    psql -U "${POSTGRES_USER}" -d grafana_db -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE grafana_db TO grafana_user;"
```